# Why nortification doesn't appear in Cordova (on Android)?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, toast, web-frontend

I have to buttons on a page and I want nortification appear on buttons click. But nothing happens.
I added **document.getElementByClassName...** and **buttonController** functions. But nortification not working on buttons click.

UPDATE: I tried to add
`<script src="js/index.js"></script>` before link, but nothing changed.

Here is HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src 'self' data: content:;">
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
        <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <title>Button Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <button type="button" class="btn">Click Me!</button>
     <button type="button" class="btn">Click Me too!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is JavaScript:

```
    var app = {

    initialize: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
    document.getElementByClassName("btn").addEventListener("click", buttonController());
    },

    onDeviceReady: function() {
        this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },

    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }

    alertDismissed: function () {
    }

    buttonController: function () {
    navigator.notification.alert(
        'Button Pressed!',  // message
        alertDismissed,         // callback
        'Title',            // title
        'Button Name'                  // buttonName
    );
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

this works fine

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Notification Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.6.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Empty
    }

    // alert dialog dismissed
    function alertDismissed() {
        // do something
    }

    // Show a custom alert
    //
    function showAlert() {
        navigator.notification.alert(
            'You are the winner!',  // message
            alertDismissed,         // callback
            'Game Over',            // title
            'Done'                  // buttonName
        );
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p><a href="#" onclick="showAlert(); return false;">Show Alert</a></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, but would be nice to figure out why those version isn't working, also I added `<script src="js/index.js"></script>` before `<link>` but still not working.